# Xampp Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pthreads.dll'

Tags: php, xampp, pthreads

After downloading the latest version of `pthread`, coping `php_pthreads.dll` file into `C:\xampp\php\ext` folder and `pthreadVC2.dll` to `C:\xampp\php` folder and restarting `apache`, when i try to use `composer update` command i get this error:

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx_pro> composer update
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pthreads.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pthreads.dll (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pthre
ads.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pthreads.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pthreads.dll (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pthreads.d
ll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
```

here the name of `php_pthreads` file isn't `php_php_pthreads.dll.dll` and i'm interested why this file name is wrong on output

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

i also added `"ext-pthreads": "*"` to `composer.json`

Comment: This is the same problem for me, .. Did you fix it ?

Comment: @obeid_s no i can't

Comment: i think its something with c++ -v .. i dont know.